# How I can call a Partial View from any controllers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working with ASP.net MVC4 and view engine razor.
How I can call a Partial View from any controllers?
I have this View: Reclamante = Claimant, Victima = Victim, Conductor = Driver and DRC
in each controller I need to call a partial view "Registro de Persona", as I can do?
In code I have this:
View:

```
$("#newVictima").click(function () {
    $('#dialogVictima').load('@Url.Action("raRegistroPersona", "raTabVictima", new { area = "Reclamos" })',
            function (response, status, xhr) {
                $('#dialogVictima').dialog('open');
         });
    });
```

Controller (raTabVictima)

```
public ActionResult raRegistroPersona(){
    return View("_raRegistroPersona");
}
```

I want to use the view partial ("Registro de Persona") in each controller and not create the same partial view for each controller, Ho I can do it?

[image]

Comment: use a partial with child action `@Html.Action("Action", "Controller")`

Comment: put a partial view inside your Shared folder and call it

Comment: @Dave A, I need call to partial view from controller no from view.

Comment: **I want to use the view partial ("Registro de Persona") in each controller and not create the same partial view for each controller, Ho I can do it?** This makes no sense. please clarify. Partial views ARE NOT CALLED from controllers.

Comment: I have a view partial ("Registro Persona"), in the tabs I have  Reclamante = Claimant, Victima = Victim, Conductor = Driver and DRC in this I call the same partial view ("Registro Persona") from this four controllers I create four view I don't like is redundant I like to have one partial view and call from any controllers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RedirectToAction("Action Name", "Controller Name", new { area = "Area Name" });
```

Comment: Pankaj Garg, I need to call the partial view from controller, no from view

Answer (score 0):

I want to show menu in controllers of area. And menu is on the top of MVC structure.

```
@{Html.RenderAction("UserMenu", "MyController", new { area="" });}
```

and it worked for me.